# Can we say 'I will give this dictionary to someone that wants to have it'?

Tags: clauses

The original sentence is:

> I will give this dictionary to **whoever** wants to have it. (1)

Can we say:

> I will give this dictionary to **someone that** wants to have it. (2)

Or:

> I will give this dictionary to **anyone that** wants to have it. (3)

Furthermore, can 'that' be dropped?

> I will give this dictionary to **someone** wants to have it. (2')
>
> I will give this dictionary to **anyone** wants to have it. (3')

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=give+it+to+someone+who%2Cgive+it+to+someone+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgive%20it%20to%20someone%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20it%20to%20someone%20that%3B%2Cc0), we're much more likely to *give it to someone **who** wants it*, not ***...that** wants it*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, I never would have thought of using Google Books N-gram Viewer with that! Expressive, compelling evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these sentences are correct and natural.

> I will give this dictionary to someone that wants to have it. (2)
> I will give this dictionary to anyone that wants to have it. (3)

No one will think twice about hearing you speak these sentences. Writing is another matter. Readers with very traditional views will object to the use of **that** with reference to people. There are very few readers like this, but they exist. Know your audience.

You cannot remove the relative pronoun in sentences such as these. The words **someone** and **anyone** are objects of the preposition **to**. They cannot also serve as the subjects of the verb **wants**. That role must be filled by a relative pronoun.

Other kinds of clauses can be reduced, and I encourage you to investigate the differences.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed interpretation! I am not sure about the second paragraph, and my understanding is that (2) and (3) can be safer if 'that' is replaced with 'who', and (2') and (3') are not grammatical since the relative pronoun 'who' should present - is it correct?

Comment: That is all correct.

Comment: Much appreciated, I am getting it now.